# Save datas in user_id iOS using Alamofire

Tags: php, ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

How could I store all data forms in a particular user id? I have a registration page, so each user will have a different user_id. Then I have forms to fill their basic information, education etc.

For example, suppose user(person) 'A' has registered in the registration page for that "ABCD" random user_id is created and for user(another person) 'B' also registered so "EFGH" user_id is generated.

So their data has to be stored in a particular user id according to their registered user id( A' datas have to store in "ABCD" and B's further information have to store in "EFGH". How could I do this in Alamofire?

My post request for Alamofire is as follows,

```
 @IBAction func eduSave(_ sender: UIButton) {
   let parameters: Parameters=[

            "institute_name":univ.text!,
            "degree_name":grad.text!,
            "start_year":cityP.text!,
            "end_year":enYear.text!,
            "degree_city":proj.text!,
            "degree_country":eduCountry.text!
        ]

   //Sending http post request
        Alamofire.request(URL_USER_EDUCATION, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
            {
                response in
                //printing response
                print(response)

                //getting the json value from the server
                if let result = response.result.value {

                    //converting it as NSDictionary
                    let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary
                      let retrievedString: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "user_id")

                }
        }

        let experience = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "experience") as! ExperienceViewController

        self.present(experience, animated: true)

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with iPhone developer @ Muhammed Azharuddin, by creating a class for user defaults to store datas in user_id

```
extension UserDefaults{

    static let isLoggedIn = "com.xyz.AlotTest1isLoggedIn"
    static let userId = "com.xyz.AlotTest1userId"

}
```

And call this extension in parameters after @IBAction

```
 let parameters: Parameters=[

    "institute_name":univ.text!,
    "degree_name":grad.text!,
    "start_year":cityP.text!,
    "end_year":enYear.text!,
    "degree_city":proj.text!,
    "degree_country":eduCountry.text!,
    "user_id" : AuthService.instance.userId ?? ""
]


print(parameters)

//Sending http post request
    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_EDUCATION, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
        {
        response in
        //printing response
        print(response)

        //getting the json value from the server
        if let result = response.result.value {



            let re = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user_id") as! Array<Parameters>
            print(result)

            let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

            //This class variable needs to be defined every class where you set or fetch values from NSUserDefaults



        }
}
let ViewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Bar", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "experience") as UIViewController
self.present(ViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```